# Jade/Angular - for loop in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, pug

I am completely new to Jade and Angular and hope you can give me a hint.

```
...
- for (var j = 0; j < p.length; j++)
       tr
          td= j + 1
          td= price(value='p[j].somedbstuff')
...
```

the last td should look like

```
<price value="somedbstuff" />
```

in HTML, but gives me an error (undefined is not a function).

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: I think your line td= price(value='p[j].somedbstuff') should be changed to td = price(value='+p[j].somedbstuff+')/

Comment: Already tried this yesterday and right now again. Unfortunately still gives me an error.
Unexpected token )

Comment: if you could create a fiddle example it would be helpful to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use `each` instead of `for` for a much cleaner syntax.

I assume `price` is an angular directive and the result you want looks like that :

```
<tr>
  <td>
    1
  </td>
  <td> 
    <price value="50"></price>
  </td>
</tr>
```

In jade :

```
 each item, index in p
      tr
        td= index + 1
        td
          price(value=item.somedbstuff)
```

`each` give you the index as second parameter so you don't need to use a for loop and use an additional variable.

Comment: Super awesome, exactly what i needed! Works great! Thx for the hint!

Comment: Glad it worked out. If you feel the answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark :)